# Plotting a signal and it's spectrogram on the same datetime axis

Tags: python, matplotlib, spectrogram

I'm having difficulty lining up data (datetime stamps, values) with a spectrogram of that data in the time domain.
I had assumed that simply adjusting the span of the spectrogram across the first and last time stamps and have them share the x-axis when plotting would have worked but instead I get a smaller spectrogram width than I would have thought.

[image]

Below is the code I'm using to generate the plot:

```
fig = plt.figure()
ax1, ax2 = fig.subplots(2, 1, sharex=True)
ax1.plot(time_stamps, signal_returns)
ax1.xaxis_date()
date_format = mdates.DateFormatter('%H:%M:%S.%f')
ax1.xaxis.set_major_formatter(date_format)
ax1.set_xlabel('Time')
ax1.set_ylabel('Amplitude')

powerSpectrum, freqenciesFound, time, imageAxis = ax2.specgram(signal_returns, Fs=fs, NFFT=nfft,
                                                                   xextent=(time_stamps[0], time_stamps[-1]))
ax2.set_xlabel('Time')
ax2.set_ylabel('Frequency')
plt.show()
```

I also wrote up some sample code to replicate the issue but it didn't replicate the issue at all. I'm stumped as to the cause, does anyone have any ideas? Should changing the size of the windowing function or number of samples per FFT widen or shrink the spectrogram?

```
    samplingFrequency = 100000
    s1 = np.arange(start=1, stop=12000001, dtype=float)
    data = np.random.randn(4000000)
    zeros = np.zeros(4000000)
    s2 = np.append(zeros, data)
    s2 = np.append(s2, zeros)
    print("Size of s1 array: ", s1.size, "size of s2 array: ", s2.size)

    # Generate some timestamp looking things
    today = datetime.datetime.now()
    time_stamps = np.full(s1.shape, today, dtype=object)
    for index, time_offset in enumerate(s1):
        time_stamps[index] = time_stamps[index] + datetime.timedelta(microseconds=time_offset)

    # Convert datetimes to matplotlib dates for plotting
    time_stamps_dates = mdates.date2num(time_stamps)

    # Plot
    fig = plt.figure()
    ax1, ax2 = fig.subplots(2, 1, sharex=True)
    ax1.plot(time_stamps_dates, s2)
    ax2.xaxis_date()
    date_format = mdates.DateFormatter('%H:%M:%S.%f')
    ax1.xaxis.set_major_formatter(date_format)
    ax1.set_xlabel('Time')
    ax1.set_ylabel('Amplitude')

    spec, freq, time, imageAxis = ax2.specgram(s2, Fs=100000, NFFT=1024,
                                               xextent=(time_stamps_dates[0], time_stamps_dates[-1]))
    ax2.set_xlabel('Time')
    ax2.set_ylabel('Frequency')

    plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Maybe do it the other way round, instead of plotting `signal_returns` first use the returned values from `ax2.specgram` and plot the newest. Is `signal_returns` just a 1d series, basically a contatenation of measurements, that you would like to split and plot, each measurement is a row in the spectrogram, right? Then you might need to slice the newest signal out of `signal_returns` instead of plotting the complete series.

Comment: That's right, signal_returns is a ndarray with x elements in it, the spectrogram then takes runs across that array with NFFT sample windows for the FFTs that form the columns of the spectrogram.
I think my problem has to do with the sample frequency not corresponding to the sample frequency of the sensor maybe

Comment: You have the time stamps, so you know the sample frequency of then sensor, right? `ax1.plot(time_stamps, signal_returns)` should plot the complete series, if there is no x limit, while the spectrogram will wrap that signal many many times. So the time axis in the spectrogram will also wrap, right. Maybe do not use a date, but instead say 0 tp 30 seconds.

Comment: Also your plot "feels" a bit strange. Usually a more intuitive way is to align the amplitude (or frequency) in the 1d plot with the one in the spectrogram. see e.g. [here](https://cdn-learn.adafruit.com/assets/assets/000/011/423/medium640/microcontrollers_spectrum_empty.png?1380743671) or [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectrogram#/media/File:PAL-I.png). You would have to transpose the spectrogram, then  a row in it is along the 1d plot with the amplitude (or freq).

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Waterfall_plot#/media/File:Aaronia_Spectrum_Analyzer_Software.jpg